# Angular creating array on model change not working

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have `quantity:number` variable and `quantityArray: number[]` array. In my template i have two buttons and one input field. when i click the buttons or  when i change input field `quantity` must increment or decrement. and `quantityArray` must change its length according to quantity. When i click buttons everything works fine. But when i change the input field quantity changes but length of `quantityArray` is not changing

here's [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/3CXgIebjKu91ltPy6hy9?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure the value is treated as number

```
 return new Array<number>(Number(qty));
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/rwh776WpJEi17sIEqcxO?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Change input type to "number". It's text for now.

```
<input type="number" [ngModel]="quantity" (ngModelChange)="qtyChange($event)">
```